# Ability to export the History Tracking details of a custom object to excel

Tags: servicecloud, history-tracking, sales-cloud

Is it possible to export History Tracking details of a custom object to excel?

Answer (score 0):

Create a report with all the history fields like: History Id, Field/Event, Old Value, New Value, Parent Id for that Custom object and run the report. Finally do export to excel upon clicking on "Export Details" button.